# Extracting a user input from a text file

Tags: file, python-3.x, file-io

I have a text file that is called *paintingJobs.txt*, each line is structured in this way:

Estimate Number, Estimate Date, Customer ID, Final Total, Status (E for Estimate, A for Accepted job or N for Not accepted), and Amount Paid.
Here is an extract:

> E5341, 21/09/2015, C102, 440, E, 0
>
> E5342, 21/09/2015, C103, 290, A, 290
>
> E5343, 21/09/2015, C104, 730, N, 0

I would like the user to input any *Estimate number* and for that line to be outputted. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I came up with but it doesn't work as required:

```
def option_A():
    es_num = str.upper (input ("Please enter the estimate number: "))
    with open('paintingJobs.txt', 'r') as file:
        line = file.readline ()
        print (line, end = '')
        if es_num in file:
            #print whole line 

        else:
             print("Not found")
```

I would like to display the  information in this format

> Estimate Number: *the estimate number*
>
> Customer ID: *the customer ID*
>
> Estimate Amount: *the final total*
>
> Estimate Date: *the estimate date*
>
> Status: *the status*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the line, I suggest you to simply iterate on each line of the file as follows:

```
def option_A():
    es_num = str.upper (input ("Please enter the estimate number: "))
    result = "Not found"
    with open('paintingJobs.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if es_num in line:
                result = line
                break
    print(result)
```

To format the display, you can split the line with comma as separator to get a list of information. Then format your display, as follows:

```
data = result.split(',')
print("Estimated number:{0}".format(data[0]))
print("Customer ID:{0}".format(data[2]))
...etc...
```

Then if you need some data which are more complex to retrieve from the text file, the powerful way is to use regex with for instance the method `re.match(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a question why have you used the break outside a while loop?

Comment: I used the break to stop the "for" loop at first match. Reading your post I assumed that only one line can match the user input. Am I right ?

Comment: so you can use 'break' to stop any type of loop?

Comment: Yes. In order to format the displayed information, you should use `result.split(',')` to split the line into a list of information of the line (using comma as separator).

Comment: Thank you for your help.